# Scrolling page automatically

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have written following code in page content section in jQuery mobile, Whenever i tried to write anything in textbox, the page automatically scrolls up & down.that is my screen does not remain fixed on textbox in which i am writing it scrolls up and down. Please help,
thanks.

```
<div data-role="content" class='content'>

   <div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>Purchased Product</h3>
   <h5 id="list">
   <p1></p1>
   </h5>
   <hr/>
   <h4></h4>
   <hr/>
   </div> <!-- collapsible -->


  <div data-role="collapsible">

   <h3>Customer Information</h3> 

   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""  />
</div>  <!--fieldcontain  -->

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value=""  />
</div>  <!--fieldcontain -->

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="address">Address :</label>
    <textarea name="address" id="address"></textarea>
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
</div>  <!--fieldcontain -->


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="pcode">Postal Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode" value=""  />
</div>  <!--fieldcontain  -->

     </div><!--collapsible -->   

<fieldset>
<a href="#page_dashboard" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Cancel</a>
   <form>
    <input type="submit" value="order" />
   </form> 
  <!-- <a href="#page_order" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="button_order">Order</a>-->
</fieldset>
</div><!-- content -->
```

when i don't write `<input type="submit" value="order" />` line in above code, my page doesn't scroll, but when i include this line, page starts scrolling why ??

Answer (score 0):

$.mobile.silentScroll

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

> **$.mobile.silentScroll (method)**
>  Scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners. 
>  ·
>   Arguments: yPos (number, defaults to 0). Pass any number to scroll to
>   that Y location. Examples:
>
> ```
> //scroll to Y 100px
> $.mobile.silentScroll(100);
> ```

Comment: i just found that if i don't write <input type="submit" value="order" /> in above code, page doesn't scroll..but when i include it, page starts scrolling.why??